# User Controls not working in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio, user-controls

A user control that was working is no longer being picked up in the ASPX file.

ASPX File

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="Uc1" TagName="ContactForm" Src="~/Controls/VFEmailForm.ascx"  %>

<uc1:VFEmailForm ID="VFEmailForm" runat="server" />
```

It was working but now isn't. A green line appears under the uc1:VFEmailForm and when you type Uc intellisense doesn't show Uc1. It is as though the register statement does not work - well it obviously doesn't. This was all working prior to upgrading to Visual Studio 2015.

I've shown part of my web.config file as ancient posts have suggested this may be the cause.

Web.config

```
<pages>
  <namespaces>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
  </namespaces>
  <controls>
    <add tagPrefix="webopt" assembly="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms" namespace="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms" />
    <add tagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" />
  </controls>
</pages>
```

If there is a guru out there who can fix this I would appreciate it.

Comment: Why don't you drag and drop your usercontrol from directory folder to your aspx page.

Comment: Echo what Suprabhat said above. Remove it from the ASPX, add it back in using design view. That usually fixes what ever references are not correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was also in your situation a bit time ago.

1 .Try using the same tag name in both lines :
As in your case

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="uc1" TagName="ContactForm" Src="~/Controls/VFEmailForm.ascx"  %>
<uc1:ContactForm ID="VFEmailForm" runat="server" />
```

2. If it helps then ok, otherwise after making this change , try restarting the visual studio. 
   This procedure helped me out.

Comment: When I tried this is still didn't work. However I created an empty user control and tried to create a tag and it also failed, I cleaned and rebuilt the project and on the third attempt it Did work! Emboldened by this success I rebuilt my control ( which also had a tag inside it) and all is now working. So thank you for your suggestions as one way or another they led to solving the problem even though it isn't entirely clear to me what caused it.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when building under x64. I switched to x86, rebuilt the project and VS 2015 worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I use Visual studio 2017, and faced a similar problem: Having green, wavy lines under the `tagName` instead the whole line, i.e., `<Uc1:***ContactForm*** ...>`. As part of this, I was getting this error:

> Element ContactForm is not a known element.

[A solution posted by @mitoutsnd on ASP.NET](https://forums.asp.net/p/1149596/5390736.aspx?Re+Element+a+user+control+is+not+a+known+element+) solved the problem by suggesting that I use:

<kbd>Build</kbd> > <kbd>Rebuild Solution</kbd>

This solved my problem.

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: @Yatin: It's not entirely clear without looking at the referenced answer in the link, but when they say "Build > Rebuild Solution", that is the entirety of the answer. I've edited the answer to help clarify that.